# React Invalid hook call but how there is invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I'm new in react-redux and I'm trying to build a todo app with a reference but I keep getting this error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

and here is the error code:

```
   4 | import App from "./App";
   5 | import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

I can't understand how there is an error?

here are some of my files:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddTodo from './components/addTodo'
import TodoList from './components/todoList'
import VisibilityFilter from './components/visibilityFilter'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <div className="App">
      <h1>TODO Managers</h1>
      <AddTodo/>
      <TodoList/>
      <VisibilityFilter/>
    </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

addTodo.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../redux/actions";

function AddTodo({ addTodo }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.input);
  };
  const addHandler = () => {
    setInput("");
    addTodo(input);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={inputHandler}
        input={input}
        placeholder="You text here"
      />
      <button onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default connect(null, { addTodo })(AddTodo);
```

todoList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as _ from 'underscore'
import { FILTER_ALL, FILTER_COMPLETED } from '../redux/actionTypes'
import { toggleTodo } from '../redux/actions'

const Todo = ({ todo, id, toggleTodo }) => (
    <li className={todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''} onClick={() => toggleTodo(id)}>{todo.text}</li>
)

function TodoList({ todos, toggleTodo }) {
    return (
        _.keys(todos).map((id) => (
            <Todo key={id} id={id} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} todo={todos[id]} />
        ))
    )
}

const mapState = (state) => {
    if (state.visibilityFilter.activeFilter === FILTER_ALL) {
        return { todos: state.todos.data }
    } else if (state.visibilityFilter.activeFilter === FILTER_COMPLETED) {
        return ({
            todos: _.pick(state.todos.data, (todo) => todo.completed)
        })
    } else {
        return ({
            todos: _.pick(state.todos.data, (todo) => !todo.completed)
        })
    }
}

export default connect(mapState, { toggleTodo })(TodoList);
```

visibilityFilter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setFilter } from '../redux/actions'
import { Filters } from '../redux/actionTypes'

function VisibilityFilter({ activeFilter, setFilter }) {
    return (
        Filters.map((filter, i) => (
            <button
                className={filter === activeFilter ? 'active' : ''}
                onClick={() => setFilter(filter)}
                key={`filter-${i}`}>
                {filter}
            </button>
        ))
    )
}

const mapState = (state) => ({ activeFilter: state.visibilityFilter.activeFilter })
export default connect(mapState, { setFilter })(VisibilityFilter)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks ok with regard to reason 2, I would look into reasons 1 and 3 (mismatched React versions or more than one copy of React). Can you include more information about your setup? Possibly include the versions numbers of React and ReactDOM? Otherwise maybe you have React installed in the parent (or other ancestor) directory.

Comment: Hi, my react and reactDOM versions are 17.0.2 and I installed these packages: redux, react-redux, react, underscore. I had this error 2 times and I asked 2 times :) you can see in my profile, when I had this error at the first time I asked directly on stack overflow. Actually there is no problem until I use hooks... I can not understand how I get this error.

Comment: These ones are tricky, can you include the contents of your `package.json` in your question? Also a quick move that sometimes fixes things like this is deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and added package.json ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm ls react` to see which versions of react your dependencies use.